Where are pip dependencies installed in a docker image?
I have a docker file that is using poetry to install dependencies e.g.
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.12

# Install poetry
RUN pip install "poetry"

WORKDIR ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
COPY poetry.lock pyproject.toml ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/

# Project initialization:
RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false && poetry install --without test --no-interaction --no-ansi --no-root

# Copy our Flask app to the Docker image
ADD src ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

# Set the CMD to your handler (could also be done as a parameter override outside of the Dockerfile)
CMD [ "handler.lambda_handler" ]

My poetry file species a few specific test dependencies:
[tool.poetry.group.test.dependencies]
pytest = "^8.3.3"

I want to verify that those dependencies are not included in my final docker image by seeing if the pip dependencies are present (or not) in the docker filesystem.
when I inspect the container inside the docker desktop app I can view the docker filesystem.

However, I cannot find where the pip installation actually is inside my docker container file system. Where can I find the python dependencies installed by pip inside my docker container?
The reason I am digging through the docker container is to see if my test specific dependencies (e.g. pytest) are being installed or not (I do not want them to be installed).
Teh

You can ask the shell in the container where exactly Pip is
$ docker run --rm --entrypoint=bash public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.12 -c 'type pip'
pip is /var/lang/bin/pip

(This image overrides ENTRYPOINT in a way that makes constructs like this awkward: in the bash -c 'command' construct, note that --entrypoint=bash needs to come before the image name but the rest of the command after.)
That implies the Python environment is in /var/lang/bin and you can see the packages there if you really need to.
docker run --rm --entrypoint=ls public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.12 /var/lang/lib/python3.12

In practice this doesn't matter, though: since /var/lang/bin is at the front of $PATH (see the environment definition in docker inspect public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.12, or run a container with sh -c 'echo $PATH') then python, pip, &c. will all use this system Python and import statements will look in the standard place as defined by the base image.

that seems to only show me the dependencies installed by the base image. For example when my docker file contains pip install boto3 and I search within ls -l /var/lang/lib/python3.12 I don't see boto there?

Is it in /var/lang/lib/python3.12/site-packages, as with non-system packages in other Pythons?  It looks like boto3 comes preinstalled in this image.  You shouldn't normally need to dig around in an image (or in a Python virtual environment) in this level of detail; is there a higher-level problem you're trying to solve?

yes I see them in their thanks so much. I will update my question with the higher level problem I am trying to solve

If you just want to see what's installed, try docker run --rm --entrypoint=pip your-image list.

ahhh that is even better - thank your for insights and pushing for the root cause of the question
